# PSQL: Connection to the server is lost during basic query

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, psql

I've been messing around with PSQL doing some basic queries and when I run the following the server's connection is lost:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM a0, a1, a2 WHERE TRUE;
servers closed the connection unexpectedly
this probably means he server terminated abnormally
before or while processing the request.
```

After checking old users posting similar questions I've ensured that my listen_addresses = "*" inside the postgres.config file. I'm totally stumped as I'm able to run basic queries, for example:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM my_table
```

and the server remains connected. It seems to be the introduction of the WHERE clause that is causing the crash. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I too have this question

Comment: What is the result of `select (select count(*) from a0) * (select count(*) from a1) * (select count(*) from a2);` ?

Comment: What does the server log file say?